# I need the style to be changed to all occurrence of anchor element inside a div with class

Tags: css

I have a div with class fview.iNside I have a span. Then I have anchor elements inside another span, ul li, another div etc.
I need same style for all anchor elements.

I have used Font-size and color to the class . But the color is not getting updated. Font size is working fine.

The div is  dynamic one. So I cant define it as it is.

```
<div class="fview"><span>
```

{{Inside i can have any html elemnts like span, div, a, ul, li }}

```
</span></div>

.fview span a {
color:red;
font-weight : bold
}
```

I need the color change to all  elements inside fview span. Please help me

Comment: Start by writing valid CSS - that comma wants to be a semicolon. And if that’s not it, then use your browser dev tools to find out where the “wrong” color comes from.

Comment: o. sorry. it is semicolon. I typed it by mistake here.

Comment: It is working only for .fview span and immediate anchor element. If it is inside ul li , color is not working

Comment: _“Inside i can have any html elemnts like span, div, a, ul, li”_ - no, you can’t - span can not contain div, ul or li, that is invalid HTML.

Comment: _“If it is inside ul li , color is not working”_ - probably because the browser’s error correction mechanism closed the span automatically before the ul, _because_ span is not allowed to contain that. So your link then _is_ not even a descendant of the span any more, and so the selector does not match either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following css in your stylesheet and check

Try this:

```
.fview span a {
   color:red !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Also inspect the element and check if any other css not overwriting this.

Note:

The span is a inline element so you should not add any block level element inside it.

If you are using a > h2 etc the it will be incorrect.

But if you can't update the HTML then try to convert the inline element to block using css it will reflect the design.

```
display: block; // inline-block
```

Let me know if still you are facing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.fview span h4 {
color:red ;
font-weight : bold
}
```

```html
<div class="fview"><span>
<h4 >Example</h4>
</span>
</div>
```

I think thats what you want.Please check this code. I hope this works for you :)

Comment: Please leave comment before downvoting answer.

Comment: i have dynamic elements inside .fview span.

Comment: color:red !important does the work. Anyway thank you. :)